# android NullPointerException when adding value to database

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-room

I am trying to add some value to a database as:

```
 fab1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {
        /*Intent i = new Intent(PlacesActivity.this, AddItemActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
        finish();*/
        //Dialog
        AlertDialog.Builder placeLLDialog= new AlertDialog.Builder(PlacesActivity.this);
        placeLLDialog.setView(R.layout.place_add_dialog);

        final EditText todo = findViewById(R.id.placeN);
        final EditText time = findViewById(R.id.placell);
        final EditText longi = findViewById(R.id.placell2);
        final PlaceDatabase db = Room.databaseBuilder(getApplicationContext(), PlaceDatabase.class,"production")
            .build();
        placeLLDialog.setTitle("Add Place with Latitude and Longitude")
          .setPositiveButton("Add", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
               if(!todo.getText().toString().equals("") &&  //line 97 of the error
                  !time.getText().toString().equals("") &&
                  !longi.getText().toString().equals("")) {

                final PlaceSaved placeSaved = new PlaceSaved(todo.getText().toString(),
                    time.getText().toString(), longi.getText().toString());
                AsyncTask.execute(new Runnable() {
                  @Override
                  public void run() {
                    db.databaseInterface().insertAll(placeSaved);
                  }
                });
              }
            }
          })
          .setNegativeButton("Cancel", null);

        placeLLDialog.show();
```

which is giving me error:

```
 java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.text.Editable android.widget.EditText.getText()' on a null object reference
   at PlacesActivity$3$1.onClick(PlacesActivity.java:97)
   at android.support.v7.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:162)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
   at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

The line 97 of the code, as commented inside the code is an empty value checking. DOnt understand why it is causing the problem, and how I can actually insert the value to the database.

The corresponding layout is:

```
 <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/placeN"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight=".7"
            android:hint="@string/place_name"
            android:imeOptions="actionDone"
            android:singleLine="true" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/placell"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight=".7"
            android:hint="@string/latitude"
            android:imeOptions="actionDone"
            android:singleLine="true" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/placell2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight=".7"
            android:hint="@string/Longitude"
            android:imeOptions="actionDone"
            android:singleLine="true" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

I was able to add the database when I have used an activity from the fab1 clicklistner (the commented section), but not with the dialog.

**UPDATE**
This is the DAO:

```
@Dao
public interface DatabaseInterface {
  @Query("SELECT * FROM placesaved")
  List<PlaceSaved> getAllItems();

  @Insert
  void insertAll(PlaceSaved... placeSaveds);
  @Delete
  void delete(PlaceSaved... placeSaveds);
  @Update
  void update(PlaceSaved... placeSaveds);
}
```

And I am not sure if it matters, I am using ROOM persistance library for database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is legit, You need to modify your findViewByID as now your edittextes are in Dialogbox.

Try this way,

```
AlertDialog.Builder placeLLDialog= new AlertDialog.Builder(PlacesActivity.this);
LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.place_add_dialog, null);
```

and fetch your edittext like this,

```
final EditText todo = view.findViewById(R.id.placeN);
```

So, Finally replace your fab1.click() method's code with below code.

```
    fab1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            AlertDialog.Builder placeLLDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(PlacesActivity.this);
            LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.place_add_dialog, null);

            placeLLDialog.setCustomTitle(view);

            final EditText todo = view.findViewById(R.id.placeN);
            final EditText time = view.findViewById(R.id.placell);
            final EditText longi = view.findViewById(R.id.placell2);
            placeLLDialog.setTitle("Add Place with Latitude and Longitude")
                    .setPositiveButton("Add", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                            if (!todo.getText().toString().equals("") &&
                                    !time.getText().toString().equals("") &&
                                    !longi.getText().toString().equals("")) {

                                final PlaceSaved placeSaved = new PlaceSaved(todo.getText().toString(),
                                        time.getText().toString(), longi.getText().toString());
                                AsyncTask.execute(new Runnable() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void run() {
                                        db.databaseInterface().insertAll(placeSaved);
                                    }
                                });
                            }
                        }
                    })
                    .setNegativeButton("Cancel", null);

            AlertDialog alertDialog = placeLLDialog.create();
            alertDialog.show();
            alertDialog.getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE  | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_ALT_FOCUSABLE_IM);
            alertDialog.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_VISIBLE);
            //***********
        }
    });
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. error is gone, but its not adding to the database. any clue?

Comment: @BaRud, Please post the code of 'insertAll' method from your database file.

Comment: its updated. And, as I said, the database is working if I use an activity, the activity can be found at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49200154/insert-data-to-a-database-using-dialogbox , which is `AddItemActivity`

Comment: How do you know that data is not going into database ?

Comment: okay, did you try to check the data by reloading the application ?

Comment: Yes... I did that, and still its not there

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166575/discussion-between-lucifer-and-barud).

Comment: Hi, as your update is working absolutely fine, and solves my problem perfectly, when I do `adapter.notifydatasetchanged()`, it gives `ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException`. I haved checked other SO questions, but cant find the solution. May you spen few minutes plz?

Comment: @BaRud, come down to chat room please

Comment: hi, have you received my reply?

Comment: Hi @Lucifer, when you have a bit time, can you help me with the delete item please?

Comment: @BaRud, what is the problem with delete item?

Comment: Hi Lucifer, you probably remember you helped me (actually wrote the itemInsert to database for me). I was following the same steps for delete item, which is defined in the adapter. I am trying many ways that are available in the SO, but I cant manage to delete item from database and update the list at the same time.

Comment: https://paste.fedoraproject.org/paste/KiWDDJQuLx9WOXw44qorvQ is the adapter in its current stage. I have put it in BindView, because, atleast in this way, I can delete the item from database, which will be updated in the next view

Comment: Let us continue this [discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166575/discussion-between-lucifer-and-barud)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `AlertDialog.setView(R.layout.place_add_dialog);`

You first need to Inflate the Layout like below -

```
LayoutInflater lf = LayoutInflater.from(YourActivity.this);
View dialog = lf.inflate(R.layout.place_add_dialog, null);
```

then set view for dialog like -

```
myAlertDialog.setView(dialog);
```

similarly,
find your views like this -

```
EditText editText = (EditText) dialog.findViewById(R.id.editText);
```

Comment: hi, thanks for your reply, please check the comment of Lucifer's answer.